# Automatic Incrementation C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am using a DataGridView in my application that contains columns, one of them named ID.
I set the ID column to read only. My question is, if I want to add a new record to the DataGridView and the ID column automatically incrementing by 1, how do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataColumn, which is used in a DataTable, which is in turn displayed in a DataGridView, has properties for autonumbering.

Please see this cookbok:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/santowebster/AutonumberingDatatable12102008090717AM/AutonumberingDatatable.aspx

or if you want to switch to DataSets, this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yctw654b.aspx

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, but I'm loading an excel spreadsheet into the datagridview, hence not needing to create an autonumber column. Or should I?

Comment: You said that you want auto increment column.  That's how it's done.  If you don't want to do that, then use int i=1; (at loop start) i++ (inside the loop) and insert i at the first column of the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataGridView is not doing anything on the underlying data. What DataSource do you use? A DataTable (or DataSet of DataTables) can have DataColumns that autoincrement. See more about the DataGridView [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Okay, but there's a bug. You see, if you click on a new row, it autoincrements. But if you don't enter any data, click somewhere else, and then click on a new record again, it also adds a number. Like you click the first time, it turns 2, but I don't enter any info. Click back on record 1, then click on a new record, and the ID is now 3. How do I fix that?